# Update Statement Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have constructed what I thought was a simple update statement, but keep running into: General SQL error.
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Statement:

```
UPDATE        TEAM_MEMBER_TEMPLATE
SET           TEAM_MEMBER_TEMPLATE.TITLE = TEAM_MEMBER.TITLE
FROM          TEAM_MEMBER_TEMPLATE
INNER JOIN    TEAM_MEMBER
ON            TEAM_MEMBER_TEMPLATE.TEAM_MEMBER_ID= TEAM_MEMBER.ID
```

Here's what I got to work previously to make sure the table/field could be updated:

```
UPDATE TEAM_MEMBER_TEMPLATE
SET TITLE = 'TEST'
WHERE ID = 38
```

Where am I going wrong here? Running Oracle version 12.1.0.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support `FROM` in the `UPDATE`.  You can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE TEAM_MEMBER_TEMPLATE TMT
    SET TITLE = (SELECT TM.TITLE
                 FROM TEAM_MEMBER TM
                 WHERE TMT.TEAM_MEMBER_ID = TM.ID
                );
```

Note:  It is generally a bad idea to repeat data like this in the database.  Instead, you should just use `JOIN` when you want the title.